# Can I put a function in Fullcalendar's headerToolbar item?

Tags: javascript

```
headerToolbar:{
  left:'prevYear prev today next nextYear',
  center:'title',
  right:'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
},
date : moment().format('YYYY-MM')
```

While making Fullcalendar, I suddenly became curious
When I press the prev button in the headerToolbar, I want to make the variable date a month ago. Can I make it so that the function can be executed when I press the prev button?

```
/admin/visit/schedule/month?managerId"+this.managerId+"&date="+this.date
```

In this way, when the month of the calendar is changed, the variable date is changed and I am trying to call the api using it.

Comment: from the documentation https://fullcalendar.io/docs/customButtons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom button to do your 'prev' functionality, and use that instead of the included prev button, as shown.

```
headerToolbar:{
    left:'prevYear myPrevButton today next nextYear',
    center:'title',
    right:'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
},
customButtons: {
    myPrevButton: {
        text: 'Prev',
        click: function() {
            // do something
        }
    }
},
date : moment().format('YYYY-MM')
```